# More Grouping Options

Tags: 2013, document-library, grouping

Working in SP13 document library.  I am looking to group the documents into particular categories in certain view.  When I modify the view, the group feature allows me to group by two ways.  However, I would like to group further without using folders.  For an example see image below.  Looking at the image...the first group created is by 'Month'...the second group is created is by 'Year'.  However, would I proceed to group by more levels (see Mtg1/Mtg2...etc)?  Is this possible since the grouping feature by view only allows two ways to group?  Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Out of the Box its not possible.. In 2010/2007, there is a solution by [editing the XLST List View Web Part](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html).. Unfortunately since you have no design view in SharePoint 2013, it will be difficult (maybe possible)..

However you can write your own JavaScript based [Client Side Rendering (JSLink)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

Or you can create your own Treeview based Web Part (ofcourse filtering, sorting etc. need to be developed)..